# How can I make wider list children spill out of their absolutely-positioned parent?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a list with dynamically-populated items, I need it to be wider than its absolutely-positioned parent (it's a custom `<select>` element implementation).

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#testContainer {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 5px dashed orange;
}

#testLabel {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.testItem {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="testLabel">label</div>
  <ul id="testContainer">
    <li class="testItem">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppppppppp</li>
    <li class="testItem">www</li>
  <li class="testItem">cccccccccccccccccc</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It works everywhere (screenshot 1) except IE11 (screenshot 2). How can I achieve this? Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/montrealist/pen/VrrYem

[image: Chrome/Firefox/Safari]

[image: IE11]

Comment: Why are you trying this approach though?  Why are we trying to break the width of an element, with items that could be bigger?  Why not just make the parent container flexible for all of the elements added to the page.  Especially if it's not visible/is transparent.

Comment: @AndrewIce need to control the label width visually yet at the same time show all the child `li` items side-to-side to the user. It's a hard requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work without the flex, as our grandfathers taught us!

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
#testLabel {
  background: yellow;
}
#testContainer {
  background: fuchsia;
  border: 5px dashed orange;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.testItem {
  background: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="testLabel">label</div>
  <ul id="testContainer">
    <li class="testItem">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppppppppp</li>
    <li class="testItem">www</li>
    <li class="testItem">cccccccccccccccccc</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do like this :

- use `display:flex` instead of `inline-flex` in `#testContainer`
- use `width: calc(50vw - 50%)`
- **[optional for tablet/mobile]** - use `left:-50%` and `width: calc(100vw - 50%)`
- use `flex: 1` instead of `width:200px` in `.testIem`
- to avoid overlapping letters (in IE at least) use `word-wrap: break-word`

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#testContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: fuchsia;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px dashed orange;
  width: calc(50vw - 50%)
}

#testLabel {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.testItem {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #testContainer {
    right: auto;
    left: -50%;
    width: calc(100vw - 50%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="testLabel">label</div>
  <ul id="testContainer">
    <li class="testItem">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaapppppppppp</li>
    <li class="testItem">www</li>
    <li class="testItem">cccccccccccccccccc</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless i'm understanding this wrong, I would simply add an overflow-x: auto; to the css for your #testContainer.

This will allow your List Items to be fully viewed the way they should be, just with the user having to scroll instead.

So just:

```
#testContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: fuchsia;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto; /* Added this here */
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px dashed orange;
  width: calc(50vw - 50%)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not good enough - the user would then have to horizontally scroll to choose an answer (or multiple answers) in a `<select>` element.